# Draw path between to points in javascript svg

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, plot, coordinates

I am trying to draw right angle paths from specified x,y coordinates in an svg element in javascript. Note how the target can be anywhere relative to the origin (top, left, bottom, right).

I would like to use the `<path />` element and calculate its path dynamically

Please see the attached image and code example:

```
      const { x: baseX, y: baseY } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      const { x, y } = current.getBoundingClientRect();
      const { x: x2, y: y2 } = toCurrent.getBoundingClientRect();
      const xDist = (x1, x2) => Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2));
      const yDist = (y1, y2) => Math.sqrt(Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
      const originThreshold = -60;
      const targetThreshold = x2 > x ? xDist(x, x2) : ~xDist(x, x2);

      return (
        <>
          <path key={`${diagramId}-${toId}`} d={`m ${x} ${y} h ${originThreshold} v ${yDist(y, y2)} h ${targetThreshold} m 0 0`} fill='none' stroke='white' strokeWidth='2' />
        </>
      )
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it just to draw a line between the colored dots as specified

Comment: I don't understand the code and the approach. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Normally **I** would use `path` element dynamically using `document.createElementNS` and setting `d` attribute

Comment: @JanStránský please see my update

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a bit, but still it is not complete reproducible code. Could you provide what is the actual returned string?

Comment: m 417 171 h 20 v 211 h 42 m 0 0 for example

Comment: I meant the complete string, including `<path ...`

Comment: ok it would be <path d='m 417 171 h 20 v 211 h 42 m 0 0' fill='none' stroke='white' strokeWidth='2' />

Comment: looks reasonable.. could the problem be that the line is white?

Comment: no. my calculations are off is the question